# How to run one query and populate 2 classes?

Tags: php, class, object

I have two classes A and B. When populate class A, I got all data already. class B need to use part of the data, and I can arrange class B as a private object inside class A. I prefer not to query data again when populate class B. How can I get 2 classes populated by the same query, or is there a way to pass data from A to B?

Comment: try using a method on class B to import from A or a query result..

Answer (score 0):

If class B can only contain data from class A, then you could do something along the lines of;

```
public class A
{
  public string Field_1 {get;set;}
  public string Field_that_B_likes {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
  public string Field_that_B_likes {get;set;}

  public B(A obj) 
  {
    Field_that_B_likes = obj.Field_that_B_likes;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, B's data is within A's data. But it's not a string, It's s dataset with about 20 elements.

Comment: So do 20 assignments, or whatever is necessary to fill in the dataset.